# AWS IAM Policy with s3:PutObject Fails for Specific Bucket in Policy Simulator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm experiencing difficulties with an AWS IAM policy intended to grant s3:PutObject permissions for a specific S3 bucket named examplebucket. The policy works as expected when using a wildcard for the resource, but fails when I specify the bucket directly, affecting both the AWS IAM Policy Simulator and my desktop application.

Working Policy (with wildcard resource):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this fails the simulator:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The policy with "Resource": "*" successfully allows s3:PutObject operations in both the AWS IAM Policy Simulator and my desktop app (DART by APTrust). However, refining the policy to target examplebucket specifically seems to prevent the policy from allowing the same action.

Context:

examplebucket exists and is correctly named in my policy.

AWS Block Public Access is enabled on examplebucket, with no conflicting bucket policies in place as far as I can tell.

My aim is to apply the principle of least privilege by limiting the policy scope to necessary resources.

Questions:

What could be causing the failure in the more specific policy where examplebucket is directly targeted for s3:PutObject permissions?

Are there overlooked aspects or additional configurations needed when specifying a single bucket in IAM policies for s3:PutObject actions?

Comment: Not sure how much I'd trust the simulator in this case. Your policy seems fine and can be validated using awscli or other clients.

Comment: I was worried about this, but when testing the app I want to connect to my bucket, it fails or works whenever the simulator fails or works. I changed permissions once to AmazonS3FullAccess and the simulator and my app were happy, even when I stipulated the specific bucket. So I'm thinking that I'm making some silly mistake with my bucket configuration or something? Like I am not changing many default values, so this must be my lack of knowledge of AWS that is making me make a stupid mistake?

Comment: What operation are you performing against examplebucket that fails when you use the latter IAM policy? And is it using awscli, an AWS SDK, something else?

Comment: With the policy simulator I'm just asking it to do a PutObject request. With the app I'm using, DART - it's an electron app that I assume is using some sort of SDK call to S3 via credentials I've provided. I'm worried I don't know enough to answer your questions!

Comment: If I use the simulator with your 2nd policy and attempt S3 PutObject of a resource with ARN arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/cat.png then it works as expected. If I reset it and attempt to PutObject to arn:aws:s3:::examplebucketxxx/cat.png then it fails as expected with Access Denied. I have to say that I don't use the simulator much (and testing this reminds me why I don't use it).

Comment: I should point out that I was able to successfully use the Aws cli to upload a file, and when I changed the bucket policy to disallow put object requests, it failed as expected. So there’s something super simple here that I’m tearing my hair out about. I feel like if I get the simulator working when pointing specifically at my bucket, the app (dart by aptrust) will also work.

Comment: Note the warning with the simulator: "The policy simulator results can differ from your live AWS environment." Also, it seems to have some usability issues e.g. I issued PutObject on a good ARN which succeeded and then I modified the ARN to a bad ARN and clicked Run Simulation again and it succeeded (though it should have failed), almost as if it did not actually do anything. 10 minutes later I tried the same sequence and it works as expected (succeeds with good ARN and then fails with bad ARN). I don't know what else to say here other than don't trust it alone; use the awscli for real tests.

Comment: I get you. I’ve asked the developer of the app I actually want to use if more than putobject is needed. that should have been one of the first things I did! Couldn’t find the answer in the docs. Thank you for talking this through with me. I feel a bit less useless.

Comment: You were right, the developer of the app said that 4 permissions were needed. The simulator was indeed being a bit useless and misleading, as CLI testing was the best troubleshooting in the end. The four permissions were: s3:ListBucket
s3:ListMultipartUploadParts
s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads
s3:PutObject